# How to Workaround Referencing View's Controls

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, view, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I'm using Galasoft's Light MVVM for my Siverlight project.

I have setup everything as instructed: the `ViewModel` is bound to `View`'s `DataContext`;

I have a canvas named `inkCanvas` in the `View`.

When the `ViewModel` gets the updated project data, I need to reference `inkCanvas` to create a `CanvasRender` instance `public CanvasRender(Canvas canvas, ProjectData pdata)`.

The problem is in MVVM, the `ViewModel` knows nothing about `View`, so how can I reference a control (`inkCanvas`) in `View`?

P.S. (Edited): The workaround I made is: when I pass the project data to the `ViewModel`, I also pass the `inkCanvas` from `View`'s code-behind.  hmmm, now my code-behind is not clean.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't have to ever reference a specific view from your view model, in fact it should be avoided. May I ask exactly what you are intending to do with the canvas inside your view model?

Comment: @KodeKreachor, I need to use it in my `CanvasRender`, which is from a class library.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the canvas inside the CanvasRender method?

Comment: @KodeKreachor, Render all project data to the canvas, and the `CanvasRender` is from another class library.

Comment: Have you looked at Gala's Messaging class?  http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx

Comment: @dbaseman, to my best knowledge, I think Messaging is created for communicating among different `ViewModel`s right?

Comment: @PeterLee sure, but you'll have to take some kind of approach using messaging, or like the one I suggested in my answer, if you insist on having communication between your View Model and the code that renders the canvas.

Comment: @PeterLee it occurs to me that you could take Cybermaxs's suggestion of only using bindings, but extend the `Canvas` and put all your rendering code in the extension.  Add new dependency properties to your Canvas extension as needed.

Comment: Hmmm, if such simple control referencing will make my code so dirty, I doubt the MVVM pattern is not suitable for my application.

Comment: @dbaseman `extend the Canvas and put all your rendering code in the extension`, I'm quite confused, the Rendering code is part of another class library, technically, I cannot change the how it renders (render the project data to the canvas).  What I need is just a reference of the inkCanvas on the view.

Comment: @PeterLee so then import the class library into your `MyCanvas : Canvas` class.  Instead of passing a reference to `inkCanvas` into the View Model, expose any external dependencies in your `MyCanvas` class as dependency properties, and allow your View Model to bind to them.

Comment: @dbaseman, I am still confused. what's the use of adding external dependencies of `MyCanvas`? the `CanvasRender` requires a `Canvas/MyCanvas` as one of its constructor parameters, so I still need the reference to the `inkCanvas`. Or am I misunderstanding anything? Can you give me a link on what you describe?

Comment: @PeterLee I added another answer to illustrate.  The point of the extended canvas class is to flip the dependency; instead of your VM requiring a reference to the UI element, now you have a UI element that requires a reference to the VM.  This way the VM stays agnostic of the view.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments above, one way to do this is to extend `Canvas` and keep the reference to `CanvasRender` inside that class.

```
public class MyCanvas : Canvas
{
    private CanvasRender _canvasRender;
    private ProjectData _data;

    public ProjectData Data
    {
        get { return _data; }       
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            _canvasRender = new CanvasRender(this, _data);
        }
    }

    public MyCanvas() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

You'd probably want to also make `ProjectData` a Dependency Property so that it's bindable.

This allows you to maintain the MVVM pattern, because now you can write in XAML:

```
<local:MyCanvas ProjectData="{Binding ViewModel.ProjectData}" />
```

Comment: OK.  Thanks for your reply.  I will try it ASAP, and let you know how it works.

Comment: I extended my canvas, but now I have new problem, how to get the `CanvasRender` inside of the `MyCanvas`.  I need to expose another property called `CanvasRender`?

Comment: @PeterLee I don't really know ... I thought you would instantiate `CanvasRender` inside the extended Canvas.  Are you saying you need to bind it as a XAML property to the extended Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM Pattern, you won't reference a Control directly in ViewModel. In MVVM, all is "binding". You inkCanvas will be binding to a property in your ViewModel.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly StrokeCollection _mystrokes;

    public MyViewModel ()
    {
        _mystrokes= new StrokeCollection();
        (_mystrokesas INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged += delegate
        {
            //the strokes have changed
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public StrokeCollection MyStrokes
    {
        get
        {
            return _mystrokes;
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<InkCanvas Strokes="{Binding MyStrokes}"/>
```

**Edit :**

Maybe the workaround for your case is to use EventToCommand : this allow tobind an UI event to an ICommand directly in XAML ( and use Args to pass a ref to the inkCancas)

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=LoadedCommand}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  but as I stated very clearly that my `CanvasRender` requires me to pass a `Canvas` parameter, not the properties of the `inkCanvas`

Comment: can you make if more clear for me?  Where to pass the `inkCanvas`? And also in order to call this, I have to define an event?

Comment: you can bind every events (Loaded, KeyUp, MouseDown...) of inkCanvas to a custom command with args. With PassEventArgsToCommand=True, I think you can pass RoutedEventArgs (and the sender) to your custom command in the view model. I have not the time to test this but i think the road is clear ...

Comment: Unfortunately, `e.OriginalSource` is always null when Loaded event is triggered. public RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> CanvasLoadedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>((e) =>
                {
                    theCanvas = e.OriginalSource as InkPresenter;
                });
            }
        }

Comment: @peter You should probably be using the CommandParameter property instead of the PassEventArgsToCommand property. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your going to use the EventToCommand approach (which you tried in another answer), then instead of using the PassEventArgsToCommand property use the CommandParameter property and bind it to your Canvas.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=CanvasLoadedCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=inkCanvas}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Then in your ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private Canvas m_canvas;

    public RelayCommand<Canvas> CanvasLoadedCommand { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel() 
    { 
        CanvasLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand<Canvas>(canvas =>  
        { 
            m_canvas = canvas;
        }); 
    }
}
```

So as soon as your canvas is loaded, you should then have a reference to it saved in your view model.